# Undefined index for mysql result

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
  <?php


$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 5")or die(mysql_error());



if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
}
echo "<table align='left' CELLPADDING='50' >";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    if ($row['photoid'] == NULL){

$date_string = $row['date'];

$date = strtotime($date_string);
$date = date('m/d/y', $date);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td  style='width: 750px'>" .$row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 700px'>" . $row['news'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px'>" . $date . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT news.title,news.date,news.news,photo.photo FROM news, photo WHERE news.photoid = photo.photoid ORDER BY date DESC") or die(mysql_error());
        $row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $date_string = $row['date'];

$date = strtotime($date_string);
$date = date('m/d/y', $date);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 750px'>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 700px'>" . $row['news'] . "</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px'>" . $date . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<td style='width: 800px'>" . '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row["photo"] ).'" >' . "</td>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

SO the website shows a news column, the code gets the news data from the database, if there is a photoid (if the news has a photo to go with it) then it adds the news to the table with a photo. If there is no photo is adds the news to the table without one. Simple. At the moment for testing I have two news articles both with photos, the first one works perfectly then the second errors

```
Undefined index: photoid in
```

For the line  `if ($row['photoid'] == NULL){`. There is a photoid.

Comment: You don't select that column in your query so it doesn't exist

Comment: Are you sure you have a column in your `news` table called `photoid`?

Comment: You don't have a column name `photoid` in your database

Comment: For one thing, you're mixing MySQL APIs in a few areas `mysql_error()`, so you're not going to get any errors back.

Comment: var_dump row and check how it looks like. Check for that particular index and if you don't have it, try to select it and any other columns you want, specifically, without *

Comment: Yes there is photoid in my news table, it does all exist and my sql statement does get it. As written it works for the first news article just not for the second.

Comment: var_dump just stopped the page from loading altogether. I changed the sql statement to select the columns but it made no difference, the first news posts perfectly. The second one posts without the picture and with that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if variable/key is set before checking the value. Try this:

```
if (isset($row['photoid']) && $row['photoid'] == NULL){
```

Comment: This has created another problem, it is infinately posting the first news article xD forever and forever just  the same one.

Comment: Use different variable names for $result and $row in the query inside the loop. Something like $result2 and $row2

Comment: You are a genius, well I have learnt something new. This fixed all my problems thanks.

Comment: You do know that you should mark an answer as solved right? It's not nice to leave the people that helped you in the air. I see this is not your first time doing this